# pci_lookup_name how to?

Tags: linux, gpu, pci

I'm new to `libpci`.
I wrote a C program, that can dectect the GPU and give its `vendor_id` and `device_id`. Now I don't know if I can get the `vendor_name` from its ID using `libpci`.

```
vendor = pci_lookup_name(pci_access, buffer, sizeof(buffer), PCI_LOOKUP_VENDOR, radeon->vendor);
```

I worte this code but it doesn't seem to work. Help me out, with some documentation, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You have an up-to-date  pci.ids file?

Comment: should i scan this file `pci.ids` or use `pci_lookup_name`?

Answer (score 0):

## Documentation

The documentation for that library seems pretty spotty.

`lspci` on linux uses it for populating it's pci information, so I'd recommend the following:
   * [lspci source code](https://github.com/gittup/pciutils/blob/gittup/lspci.c#L292)
   * `pci.h` header file (located at `/usr/include/pci/pci.h` on ubuntu, once you install libpci-dev)

## Your Code

As far as your code, it looks like you're missing the device id at the end of the va_args. Not sure why it's required, but it's documented in `pci.h`.

Try this instead:

```
vendor = pci_lookup_name(pci_access, buffer, sizeof(buffer), PCI_LOOKUP_VENDOR, radeon->vendor_id, radeon->device_id);
```

[This](https://github.com/gittup/pciutils/blob/gittup/lspci.c#L292) looks like the relevant line in the `lspci` source